# Reinstall grub on serveur (Kimsufi)

Tags: grub

I really messed up my grub and cannot boot from disk anymore, I have to boot with the netboot.

Any good link on how to reinstall grub correctly on my server ?

Thanks.

PS: my os is debian 8 and I have 4 partitions, /boot  root(/) /home and swap

Comment: Is it somehow different from installing GRUB on a regular BIOS-based system?

Comment: I suggest you run `boot-repair` from a Live Boot disc. If it's not installed, you should be able to add it to the RAMdisc with the usual installation software.